# One router is not triggered when declaring routers in different files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I would like to breakdown my routes in several files, typically something for the client routes and something for the api.

So I declare my app, then

```
app.use('/', clientRoutes);
app.use('/api', apiRoutes);
```

In clientRoutes:

```
module.exports = function (webapp_client_path){
    router.get('/', function (req, res) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(webapp_client_path, '/','index.html'));
    });
    return router;
};
```

In apiRoutes:

```
module.exports = function(passport){
    router.post('/signup', function(req, res) {
        console.log('signup!', req.body);

    });


    return router;
}
```

So the problem is that the apiRoutes is not triggered, if I put everything in the same cleintRoutes file it works. I've tried to change the root also ( app.use('/', apiRoutes); and inside the file  router.post('/api/signup'...) but it didn't change anything.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something basic here but can't find what it is yet. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 2):

I found the problem.

You need to execute the router then pass it as a middleware.

```
var apiRoutes = require('./routes/apiRoutes')();

app.use('/', apiRoutes);
```